# Google Spreadsheet find duplicates and delete ALL

Tags: duplicates, google-sheets, delete-row

I have a spreadsheet with duplicates rows. All the duplicate rows needs to be deleted.

Example:

```
Superman    superhero
Batman      superhero
Apple       fruit
Superman    superhero
Batman      superhero
```

after running the script I only want:

```
Apple       fruit
```

Found this script... maybe a good point to start?

```
function removeDuplicateRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();

  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;

    for(j in newData){
      if(row.join() == newData[j].join()){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the script yourself? Perhaps you can add the google-apps-script tag as well.

Comment: yeah I did, it deletes duplicates but only one and keeps one. I need them both to be deleted.

Comment: whats the expected result? remove all duplicates or remove duplicate in a same column (meaning there can still exist 2 cells with the same content in different columns?)The cells where there is still data should keep the same place than the first occurence encountered or can they be rearranged  at the top of the sheet.

Comment: It removed all duplicate rows and kept one of each set of duplicates it found, I need it to delete all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modification of a slightly different algorithm proposed in [this post](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/XZAUICCorEs/siivJWZJoLQJ) on another forum. The caveat is that it will sort your data as well as removing the duplicated rows (but that could be worked around).

```
function removeDuplicatesAndSort()
{
  var headerRow = false;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  if (headerRow) var header = data.splice(0, 1);
  data.sort();
  var counter = 0, counter2, row;
  while (counter < (data.length - 1))
  {
    row = data[counter].join(",");
    if (row == data[counter + 1].join(",")) //stuff be deleted
    {
      counter2 = 2;
      while ((counter + counter2) < data.length && row == data[counter + counter2].join(","))
      {
        counter2++;
      }
      data.splice(counter, counter2);
    }
    else //move to next row
    {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  if (headerRow) data.unshift(header[0]);
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that current row is added to `newData` as soon it is reached (if it isn't already there), so one copy is always added. 
I've edited the second loop to check if the current row exists anywhere else in the sheet before adding it to `newData`.

This solution *won't* sort your data, but *will* move the remaining rows to the top of the sheet. If you want them to stay where they are, look at [Harold's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21840619/739534).

I've written some comments to help you understand.

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  //Get the number of the last row with data
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){

    //Our current row
    var row = data[i];

    var duplicate = 0;

    //A loop with going through all rows with data
    for(var j = 1; j <= lastRow; j++){

      //A variable with the joined data of the row to compare with our current row
      var currValue = sheet.getRange(j, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues().join();
      if(row.join() == currValue){

        //If an occurrence of the current row exists, add 1 to the variable "duplicate"
        duplicate++;
      }
    }

    //The second loop will find the original row, so the duplicate variable will always
    //be at least 1, if any duplicates exist, it will be more and the row won't be pushed
    if(duplicate == 1){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want, but here a little script that will do a really specific action: Remove all duplicate by column (not across others columns) and keep the non duplicate values where they are.

```
function eradicateDuplicate(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  var cols = data[0].length;
  var objTable = {};
  for(var j in data[0]){
    objTable[j]=new Object();
  }
  for(var i in data){
    for(var j in data[i]){
      if(typeof objTable[j][data[i][j]]=="undefined"){
         objTable[j][data[i][j]]=1;
      }
      else{
        objTable[j][data[i][j]]+=1;
      }
    }
  }
  for(var i in data){
    for(var j in data[i]){
      if(objTable[j][data[i][j]]>1)data[i][j]="";
    }
  }
  sheet.getDataRange().setValues(data);
}
```